# API works fine on localhost but fails on azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am using webapi to communicate to my WPF application this works fine when I run my application under localhost but when I publish it to azure the api route gives me an error message. This makes no sense to me since both need to contain the same files. The azure website doesn't return an error when the database is empty only when data is in the table. I completed deleted my azure publish settings and database

[This is the link of my azure application](http://festival-stufv.azurewebsites.net/api/organisator)

## Domain Classes

```
public class Gebruiker
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage= "Achternaam niet ingevuld")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Achternaam")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Voornaam niet ingevuld")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email niet ingevuld")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adress niet ingevuld")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Address ")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wachtwoord niet ingevuld")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Wachtwoord")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "min length wachtwoord 5")]
    public string Passwoord { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Organisator
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Organisatie naam is niet ingevuld")]
    [Display(Name = "Organisatie naam")]
    public string Organisatie { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string FacebookLink { get; set; }

    public byte[] Pasfoto { get; set; }

    public bool Goedgekeurd { get; set; }

    // FK
    public int GebruikerId { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public Gebruiker Gebruiker { get; set; }
}
```

## fleunt api relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // LINK NEWSFEED -> COMMENTS

    modelBuilder.Entity<NewsFeed>().HasMany(s => s.Comment).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(h => h.NewsFeedId);

    // LINK GEBRUIKER -> COMMENTS

    modelBuilder.Entity<Gebruiker>().HasMany(s => s.Comment).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(h => h.GebruikerId);
}
```

## Webapi methode

```
// GET: api/Organisator
public IQueryable<Organisator> GetOrganisators()
{
    return db.Organisators.Where(s => s.Goedgekeurd == false).Include("Gebruiker");
}
```

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems there's something called `Comment` (a field maybe) in your database which is causing the failure. Can you check the database in Azure as to why serializing this field could throw an error?

Comment: yeah comment is a one to many navigation property in gebruiker(user) an organisator has a user I thought the issue was because the one to many relationship wasn't optional but this code works fine localhost :(? Maybe it has something to do with lazy loading?

Comment: My guess is that this is related to configuration used locally and on Azure. Check web.config and connection string parameters.

Comment: From your exception: *"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."* - double check that you do not have two DbContext opened at the same time. Also never return an IQueryable directly from an ActionMethod, materialize the result first (using ToList or ToListAsync).

Comment: redeployed azure from scratch works fine now really strange thanks anyway guys!

Comment: The eroro "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." indicates that MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets) is not enabled. Did you enable MARS? Take a look at this old post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/06/09/remember-to-re-enable-mars-in-your-sql-azure-based-ef-apps.aspx. It says that VS used to disable MARS for Azure databases and the error

Comment: I managed to replicate my error... it came back... but then this gentleman Pawel the great came with a solution that solved my issue. Thanks Pawel you are a man of the state. Solution add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to connectionstring.